# My wifi connection goes really slow at times. Can I set the powersaving option off permanently?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro 5,5 running Ubuntu 11.04 Natty amd64.
About one time every hour, my wifi connection speed goes really slow (I guess it goes in to powersaving mode), and I have to run `iwconfig eth1 power off` (which I have packaged in a bash script for ease) to get back to normal speed.

Is it possible to set the power option to "off" permanently so I don't have to do this manually every time the wifi driver decides to go in to powersaving mode?

Answer (score 1):

As you already have a bash script add it to the startup applications. So the script will be run when booting up the computer.or add into the command line of the startup application xterm -e followed byiwconfig eth1 power off.

Comment: I can see how that will fix my problem initially, but after an hour or so, when the driver decides to go in to powersaving mode yet again, I'd have to run the script again, so that doesn't really fix my problem.

Comment: If you run the script manually, will the computer return to powersafe mode or the problem is solved once and forever until you reboot the machine? Did you try both ways 1. via script, 2. via directly putting the iwconfig ... into the command line? Did you check the results of iwconfig before and after you run the script?

Comment: If I run the command (or the script), the problem is solved for sometime until the driver decides it should go into powersaving mode yet again. That can take half an hour or two hours, but it does always happen at some point. The wificard doesn't have a "power" property in iwconfig - I guess the driver is not fully supporting this? The only way I found out about the "fix" was from someone mentioning it on IRC. There is, btw, no difference in running it "manually" or via the script.

Comment: Then definitely (little bit too strong; most probably) it has nothing to do with powermanagement as when enter the terminal command iwconfig eth1 and you have a powermanagement it would tell you. Could you post the return of iwconfig eth1?

Comment: Would would the "power" option be if not powermanagement, then? Just asking. This is the output of `iwconfig eth1`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/619385/